# How to find the length and width of detected objects by findContours function?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, visual-c++, contour

I have an image that contains different types of flakes. This is an example image:

[image: Example image]

In this image, all black portion is a flake and I want to find the length and the width of each flake.

I used the `findContours` function to detect all these flakes. I also used the `arcLength` function for finding the length but I don't know the return value of this function.

So, is there any method to measure the perfect length and width of an object?

Comment: What do you want the algorithm to do in cases of overlapping flakes?

Comment: one of them should be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, the simplest approach is looking to the minimun rectangle that contains your flake, and this is the function to call:

[Opencv minAreaRect](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the accuracy you need.

Simplest way is to use opencv minrect function on each sub detection layer (just transport each detection countour[i] to a layer)

```
RotatedRect minAreaRect(InputArray points)
```

The output rect width and height is what you are looking for

[image]

The other tool is call convexhull. To determine this, you have to find principle direction (eigen) and find the length.  If you need to find a curved length, then you have to trace alone the non-convexhull area. it will be a bit complicated

```
void convexHull(InputArray points, OutputArray hull, bool clockwise=false, bool returnPoints=true )
```

[image]